# What are the consequences of omitting @autoreleasepool { } in main()?

Tags: objective-c, macos, memory-management, clang

Why do the Xcode 4.x templates for Objective-C *command-line* and *iOS* programs add the `@autoreleasepool {}` part wrapping `main()`'s code? Note that this doesn't happen for the *OS X* application template.

Why don't OS X applications do the same? Why don't both use the same method?

Finally, since all memory is released when any program exits, why is all of this of **practical** importance?

---

Or to ask it differently, what are the practical consequences of omitting `@autoreleasepool { ... }` in `main()` for a *command line* or an *iOS* Objective-C program?

These two pieces of code compile and seem to work equivalently:

1.

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        NSArray *array = @[@"Hello, world!"];
        NSLog(@"%@", array[0]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

2.

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    NSArray *array = @[@"Hello, world!"];
    NSLog(@"%@", array[0]);
}
```

---

Note, I only care about the explanation in the ARC context. ARC forbids the explicit use of `autorelease`.

Comment: There's no memory usage at all after `main()` returns, so there are no leaks there.

Comment: I see. What I don't get yet is why the default Xcode template for *command line tools* adds the `@autoreleasepool {}` part.

Comment: Old versions of iOS (5.1 and earlier) would emit a warning if you didn't create an autorelease pool in `main` and then autoreleased any objects.  It's likely that older versions of OS X behaved the same way.

Comment: Yeah, in a non-ARC environment you'll get lots of nasty "just leaking" messages in the console if you don't have an autorelease pool.

Comment: Ok, I get that. Then, back to the question. Does removing the `@autorelease {}` on ARC produces any actual consequence?

Comment: Cocoa expects, nay demands, that each thread have an autoreleasepool in place.  It stands to reason the entry point is the place to set it up for the main thread.

Comment: The OS X application template just calls NSApplicationMain() which will create an autorelease pool automatically. It does it for you to make sure nobody even tries to create an OS X application without an autorelease pool.

Comment: Also, note that ARC says that you cannot use autorelease in your own code. However your code is still full of autoreleased objects, it's just writing that code for you as part of the compile operation. I can see three objects in your sample code that might be autoreleased, depending on what the compiler thinks is appropriate. ARC does not turn Obj-C into a memory managed language. It just means the memory management code is written automatically at compile time. There was a fully garbage collected version of Obj-C, it was deprecated years ago.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`autorelease` doesn't work if there is no autorelease pool on the stack.

It's not really necessary to use autoreleased objects in objective-c (as you do in your examples), so you can omit it in theory, however most Apple frameworks do use autoreleased objects heavily.

Normally, every thread should have at least one autorelease pool, otherwise using any Obj-C code is very unsafe. Setting up an autorelease pool at the beginning of `main` is then a very good practice.

EDIT:

In ARC, although explicit `autorelease` is forbidden, `autorelease` calls are still there (added by the compiler). That implies the need for an autorelease pool.

This has nothing to do with releasing the memory. The very existence of an autorelease pool is necessary. Even if it isn't ever drained.

I guess that OS X doesn't add the autorelease pool to the template because the programmers can also use a garbage collector (although it is deprecated now).

EDIT 2:

Just created an OS X project and the `@autoreleasepool` is there. In fact, the only template without it is a "Core Foundation" project which is not really Obj-C, it's pure C.

EDIT 3: (After some more thinking and some googling)

With the introduction of ARC, autorelease pools were rewritten. When before they were a framework feature, now they are a language (Obj-C) feature. They are implemented differently. It seems that every new thread has an *implicit* autorelease pool now. Using `@autoreleasepool` doesn't actually create a new autorelease pool on some thread stack any more, it just puts a mark to the implicit autorelease pool (so that you can drain everything autoreleased after the mark). That means there is no way to create an example triggerring warnings or errors when `@autoreleasepool` is omitted.

However, this is considered to be an *implementation detail*, so it can be easily changed in future (or when another compiler is used!). That's why it's good practice to still set up an `@autoreleasepool` for every new thread (mentioned, for example, in `-[NSThread detachWithSelector:..]` documentation).

Comment: Thanks but this doesn't answer what I'm trying to ask. See the last part of my updated question.

Comment: Could you provide some code that will malfunction or generate warnings under ARC without an `@autoreleasepool`? Additionally, why is this not the case for OS X applications?

Comment: I couldn't actually find any use case when omitting `@autoreleasepool` would cause a crash. Interesting! I remember having crashes on older system versions.

Comment: I don't mean a crash, a compiler warning or runtime exception would be satisfactory.

Comment: Your question amounts to saying: "If I don't do the thing that's documented, my app doesn't crash and I don't get any warnings or errors. So why do the documented thing?" The answer is because if you don't do it there's no guarantees that it will always work.

Sultan's answer that the compiler generates autorelease calls when you use ARC, and thus there should be an autorelease pool is the correct one. Regardless of whether the current OS software is defensive enough to not crash if you don't supply one.

Comment: @SteveWaddicor Serious documentation should explain why the things are the way the documentation shows. One should be always able to dig deeper. Ideally until you reach machine code. I'm just trying to dig deeper and your comment doesn't help much. :-)

Comment: @RicardoSánchez-Sáez You can find enough documentation but you have to distinguish what is "documented behavior" (that is, something that won't change in future) and what is an implementation detail (something that can change in future or with another compiler).

Answer (score 3):

In your code example above, you're not using any autoreleased objects whatsoever.

But, if you were doing something like this:

```
NSString * somethingToSay = [NSString stringWithString:@"this is an autoreleased string, believe it or not"];
NSLog(@"%@", somethingToSay);
return 0;
```

The "`@autoreleasepool`" bit would actually be a bit more useful.

[Looking at Apple's documentation for autoreleasepool](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmAutoreleasePools.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000047-CJBFBEDI), they say:

> At the end of the autorelease pool block, objects that received an
>   autorelease message within the block are sent a release message—an
>   object receives a release message for each time it was sent an
>   autorelease message within the block.

So when you have *lots* of autoreleased objects (and there are plenty that you can create that end up as NSArray, NSDictionary, NSString, etc.), these autorelease pools help to keep memory freed up.

The application template includes "`@autoreleasepool`" in main.m because on devices like the iPhone or iPad, memory usage is critical and we'd want to make certain that all memory gets properly released if the application exits the "`UIApplicationMain`" (not very likely, since most people leave their iPhone apps running until rebooting, but it could happen).

Comment: I think know what autorelease pools are used for. I was asking why do we need one wrapping `main()` in Objective-C programs.

Comment: I don't believe iPhone apps will normally ever leave the "`UIApplicationMain`" method, but it might leave if the user terminates the app manually (I probably should verify this in a test app) and Apple probably has that "`@autoreleasepool`" included as a "best practice" example for making certain to clean up all autoreleased objects nicely on application exit.

Comment: Sorry but the explanation is not satisfactory. iOS is closing your background apps all the time, so I think the "apps not closing" bit is wrong. In addition, *autorelease pools* wrapping `main()` are used on OS X as well. E.g., the *command line tool* template. I'm not sure but I suspect this was the case even before the original iPhone was released (obviously, back then `NSAutoreleasePool` was used instead of `@autoreleasepool { }`).

Comment: I believe memory warnings would cause that pool to drain, but I may be wrong.

Comment: Well in MacOs, NSApplicationMain is much more likely to actually exit and the "`@autoreleasepool`" will drain.

Comment: NSApplicationMain() will still never return.

Answer (score 2):

You need it because the documentation says you need it. That should be enough, trust the documentation:

> Typically, you don’t need to create your own autorelease pool blocks, but there are some situations in which either you must or it is beneficial to do so.
>
> ...
>
> Cocoa always expects code to be executed within an autorelease pool
>   block, otherwise autoreleased objects do not get released and your
>   application leaks memory. (If you send an autorelease message outside
>   of an autorelease pool block, Cocoa logs a suitable error message.)
>
> ... There are, however, three occasions when you might use your own autorelease pool blocks:
>
> - If you are writing a program that is not based on a UI framework, such as a command-line tool.
> - ...
> - ...
>
> ...
>
> If you are writing a Foundation-only program or if you detach a thread, you need to create your own autorelease pool block.

If there is no autorelease pool... then most things will still work fine, but it is "most" things, not "all" things. They only state two reasons, however there might be other reasons that aren't documented and all of this behaviour is subject to change at any time in the future.

If you follow the recommended best practices, then your code should still work perfectly 20 years from now, but if you don't it might crash randomly once in every fifty executions starting with the next x.x.x update of the operating system.

Answer (score 1):

Probably this quote from Apple documentation would help:

> If your detached thread does not make Cocoa calls, you do not need to use an autorelease pool block.

It could be extrapolated to all threads even master one (where "main" is).

Comment: Interesting. Where's the quote from?

Comment: @RicardoSánchez-Sáez https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmAutoreleasePools.html