# Why Xcode generate autoreleasepool for iOS but not for Mac

Tags: ios, macos

When you create a new project, and check the main function in iOS project and Mac project. You can see the difference here:
for iOS:

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
    }
}
```

for Mac:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    return NSApplicationMain(argc, argv);
}
```

Do you know why there is no autorelease pool code generated for Mac?

I checked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18422190/what-are-the-consequences-of-omitting-autoreleasepool-in-main) , I do not find my answer. I am using Xcode5.0. When I create Cocoa application, there is no autoreleasepool generated. And for iOS application, if UIApplicationMain return, then application will exit, So the memory will be released. I do not see any difference between w/o autoreleasepool.